# NFePHP - Problema para protocolar com retorno da SEFAZ

Tags: php

É o seguinte:
Eu trabalho com emissão de NFe com a biblioteca NFePHP. Eu consegui pegar o retorno do protocolo na receita. Porém, na biblioteca ao utilizar:

```
$protocol = new NFePHP\NFe\Factories\Protocol();
$xmlProtocolado = $protocol->add($xmlAssinado,$protocolo);
```

tem hora que funciona e tem hora que não funciona. Eu não entendo o porque disto está acontecendo.

Segue me código a partir do protocolo:

```
if($protocolo) {
    $st = new NFePHP\NFe\Common\Standardize();
    $std = $st->toStd($protocolo);

    $cStat = $std->protNFe->infProt->cStat;
    $xMotivo = $std->protNFe->infProt->xMotivo;
    $nProt = $std->protNFe->infProt->nProt;

    $retorno = $cStat . ' | ' . $xMotivo;

    if($cStat == '100') { // Autorizada

        try {
            $protocol = new NFePHP\NFe\Factories\Protocol();
            $xmlProtocolado = $protocol->add($xmlAssinado,$protocolo);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $er = $e->getMessage();
            $result = ["result"=>"erro",
                       "mensagem"=>utf8_decode($er)." add Protocolo DUPLICIDADE 4.00"];
                       if($result["result"]!== "ok") goto end;
        }

    }
    else {
        echo "Não deu certo";
    }

} //fim do $protocolo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boa tarde, também trabalho com **NFePHP**. Na nova versão da biblioteca (5.00) houve uma mudança no tratamento para adicionar o **protocolo* de autorização* ao **xml** assinado.

Então vamos lá:

Quando você aplica este código:

```
$st = new NFePHP\NFe\Common\Standardize();
$std = $st->toStd($protocolo);
```

a sua variável `$std` poderá ter dois retornos possíveis, por isso, que você ao utilizá-la as vezes funciona e as vezes não funciona, pois a maneira de acessar o `$cStat` muda conforme o resultado, você pode conferir as possibilidades de add protocolo na documentação da API [aqui](https://github.com/nfephp-org/sped-nfe/blob/master/docs/Complements.md)

Os dois retornos possíveis são: autorizadas ou retornará apenas o recibo.

O tratamento que você fez para a autorizada está correto. Porém, para o recibo você vai precisar acessar as variáveis `$cStat` e `$xMotivo` assim:

Autorizada:

```
$cStat = $std->protNFe->infProt->cStat;
$xMotivo = $std->protNFe->infProt->xMotivo;
```

Somente o Recibo:

```
$cStat = $std->cStat;
$xMotivo = $std->xMotivo;
```

Adaptando o seu código de uma maneira que sua variável `$retorno` te informe exatamente o que está acontecendo:

```
    if($protocolo) {
        $st = new NFePHP\NFe\Common\Standardize();
        $std = $st->toStd($protocolo);

        $cStat = $std->protNFe->infProt->cStat;
        $xMotivo = $std->protNFe->infProt->xMotivo;
        $nProt = $std->protNFe->infProt->nProt;

        //aqui trata se não tem retorno autorizada, pegando o do recibo
        if(!$cStat){
             $cStat = $std->cStat;
             $xMotivo = $std->xMotivo;
        }    

        $retorno = $cStat . ' | ' . $xMotivo;

    //ao chegar aqui o $cStat do recibo não será 100 com isto cairá no else te dando $retorno
    if($cStat == '100') { // Autorizada

        try {
            $protocol = new NFePHP\NFe\Factories\Protocol();
            $xmlProtocolado = $protocol->add($xmlAssinado,$protocolo);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $er = $e->getMessage();
            $result = ["result"=>"erro",
                       "mensagem"=>utf8_decode($er)." add Protocolo DUPLICIDADE 4.00"];
                       if($result["result"]!== "ok") goto end;
        }

    }
    else {
        echo $retorno;
    }

} //fim do $protocolo
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: cara, muito obrigado. faz totalmente sentido. Eu não tinha me atentado a isto. Tem um monte de colegas apanhando com isto! muito obrigado. Vai me ajudar muito mesmo. Que alivio